# How to use touchesBegan again after touchesEnded

Tags: ios, swift, touch, draw, cgpath

My result of code is after I draw line already, it will detect that correct or wrong position and show result, but after I have already draw it will show result suddenly. I want it to show result after I draw more than 1 line. How can I do ?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    let touch = touches.first
    swiped = false
    lastPoint = touch?.location(in: self)
    firstPoint = lastPoint
}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    if let touch = touches.first {
        swiped = true
        currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        drawShapeLayer(from: lastPoint, to: currentPoint)
        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    if !swiped {
        drawShapeLayer(from: lastPoint, to: lastPoint!)
    }


    if  c1.contains(firstPoint) && c3.contains(linePoint) && c2.contains(lastPoint){
        AlertView.instance.showAlert(title: "Hooray!", message: "You made it!", alertType : .success)
    }

    else {
        AlertView.instance.showAlert(title: "Oops!", message: "You've almost got it.", alertType : .failure)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, it may be easier to use the UISwipeGestureRecognizer
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer

They abstract out a lot of stuff and simplifies things like state and path.

Some of this confuses me

```
if !swiped {
    drawShapeLayer(from: lastPoint, to: lastPoint!)
}
```

Shouldn't that be

```
if !swiped {
    let touch = touches.first
    lastPoint = touch?.location(in: self)
    drawShapeLayer(from: firstPoint, to: lastPoint!)
}
```

Also in this

```
  if  c1.contains(firstPoint) && c3.contains(linePoint) && c2.contains(lastPoint){
        AlertView.instance.showAlert(title: "Hooray!", message: "You made it!", alertType : .success)
    }
```

There will be no times that linePoint != lastPoint.

Unless 'drawShapeLayer' changes these, in which case your data encapsulation is a little confusing.